# Cannot find rxjs select operator used by ngrx store.select

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, angular

Cannot find select operator from rxjs library.

As I understand and explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921239/what-is-store-select-in-ngrx), ngrx store uses select operator from rxjs library when we call `store.select` method. The way it is currently working is if I imort the whole rxjs library:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

But this imports the whole rxjs operators, I only want to import the operators I need.

If I exclude `rxjs/Rx` import, get this error:

```
TypeError: this.store.select(...).first is not a function
```

I have also done a global search in npm rxjs package directory and that folder doesn't have any file with select in it. Really confusing.

Comment: The `select` operator is part of [`@ngrx/core`](https://github.com/ngrx/core/blob/v1.2.0/src/operator/select.ts) and is [bound to the `Store`](https://github.com/ngrx/store/blob/v2.2.1/src/store.ts#L23). Your error relates to the `first` operator, as Martin has pointed out in his answer.

Comment: Thanks @cartant, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to import the entire library you can pick only the operators/Observables you want with for example:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
```

You can see the full list here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/src/add/operator

Comment: Thanks martin. Worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try as well**

```
npm un --save rxjs
npm un --save rxjs-compat

npm i --save rxjs@6.2.2
npm i --save rxjs-compat@6.2.2
```