# How to add typescript types to a selected slice of AppState in Angular's NGRX library?

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I'm trying to type out my AppState(first time).

My app state only has one `store.select('sunDial')` which is an Object that 
I'm really lost on how to properly add types when you select a slice from AppState.

**Question: How can I properly add types to this simple example of a component and AppState.**

I have a component:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState, SunDial } from '../app.interface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'sun-dial',
  templateUrl: 'sun-dial.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['sun-dial.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class SunDialComponent implements OnInit {
  private partOfDay: Observable<SunDial>; // is this an Observable??
  public activeInputField: SunDial; // Is this really referencing as a number?

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) { // I see this everywhere

    this.partOfDay = store.select<SunDial>('sunDial'); // select sunDial:SunDial?
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.partOfDay.subscribe(x => {
      this.activeInputField = x; 
    });
  }
}
```

And my AppState.ts

```
export interface AppState {
  sunDial: SunDial; // store.select('sunDial') create an object/observable?
}

export interface SunDial { // Is this really an Observable?
  activeInputField: number
}
```

Nothing in my WebStorm IDE is throwing errors but I really don't know how to reason about the types (basically just guessing).  Could anyone help me understand how to completely annotate the types for my `class SunDialComponent{}`

Ref:
[what is store.select in ngrx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921239/what-is-store-select-in-ngrx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look to the `select` [interface](https://github.com/ngrx/core/blob/81700e8716ad6bdd95de93b5c1549aaba94cf6fd/src/operator/select.ts#L6) :

```
export interface SelectSignature<T> {
  <R>(...paths: string[]): Observable<R>;
  <R>(mapFn: (state: T) => R): Observable<R>;
}
```

You'll notice that you can either pass a `string` or a `function`.

So instead of passing a string to the `select` method, pass a function like that :

```
this.store.select(state => state.sunDial);
```

You'll notice that your IDE will understand that the result of this line will be of type `Observable<SunDial>`.