# Angular .pipe and .subscribe undefined when selecting from ngrx store in unit tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, ngrx

I had some previously working unit tests and at some point they stopped working.

Whenever I select an observable from the ngrx store like so:

```
const observable = this.store.select(isAuthenticated);
```

and then attempt to call .pipe or .subscribe, these functions are undefined.

```
observable.subscribe(authenticated => {});
```

> TypeError: observable.subscribe is not a function

or

> TypeError: _this.store.select(...).pipe is not a function

I am importing the StoreModule and adding the appropriate model. These components work fine when not testing.

**Edit:**
I use this MockStore function to add data to the store to select. I suspect the problem is in the map function as this changed with rxjs 6. the store selection is returning a map function instead of an observable.

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


export function MockStore(mockStore: any) {

  const mockData: BehaviorSubject<Object> = new BehaviorSubject<Object>(mockStore);

  const store = TestBed.get(Store);
  const storeSpy = spyOn(store, 'select').and.callFake((fn) => {
    return map.call(mockData, fn);
  });

  return storeSpy;
}

export function MockDispatch() {
  const store = TestBed.get(Store);
  const dispatchSpy = spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callFake(() => { return; });
  return dispatchSpy;
}
```

Comment: show the select function

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you be more specific?

Comment: What is `isAuthenticated` set to?

Comment: export const isAuthenticated = createSelector(getUsersState, user.isAuthenticated);export const isAuthenticated = (state: State) => state.authenticated;

Comment: At least, you should share the minimum code for the proper understanding of the problem

Comment: `this.store.select(isAuthenticated)` That should return an observable.

Comment: what is `select` ?

Comment: Antoniossss - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921239/what-is-store-select-in-ngrx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was importing map from the wrong area

Changed:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

to:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';
```

Everything started working again.

Comment: No longer a viable import in 6.2.2