how can I access and print my state property from Store using async?
This is my Angular code for a simple counter, practicing on ngRx.
counter.reducer.ts:
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { plus, minus, reset } from './counter.actions';

export interface CounterState{
  counter: number;
};

export const initialState: CounterState = {
  counter: 0
};

export const CounterReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(plus, (state) => ( {...state, counter: state.counter + 1}) ),
  on(minus, (state) => ( {counter: state.counter - 1}) ),
  on(reset, (state) => ({counter: 0})),
);

counter.actions.ts:
import { createAction } from '@ngrx/store';

export const plus = createAction('counter +');
export const minus = createAction('counter -');
export const reset = createAction('counter Reset');

counter.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { CounterState } from '../counter.reducer';
import { minus, plus, reset } from '../counter.actions';
import { Observable, map } from 'rxjs';
import { AsyncPipe, CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'counter',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './counter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./counter.component.css'],
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class Counter {
  //c!:number;
  counterFinal$: Observable<number>; //= this.store.select("counter");
  
  constructor(private store: Store<CounterState>) {
    //this.store.select('counter').subscribe(data => this.c = data.counter);
    this.counterFinal$ = this.store.select("counter");
    
  }

  plus() {
    //this.count = this.count + 1;
    console.log('+');
    this.store.dispatch(plus());
  }

  minus() {
    //this.count = this.count - 1;
    console.log('-');
    this.store.dispatch(minus());
  }

  reset() {
    //this.count = 0;
    console.log('0');
    this.store.dispatch(reset());
  }
}

I provide the store on my main.ts like this:
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideStore({ counter: CounterReducer }),
    provideStoreDevtools({
      maxAge: 25, // Retains last 25 states
      logOnly: !isDevMode(), // Restrict extension to log-only mode
      autoPause: true, // Pauses recording actions and state changes when the extension window is not open
      trace: false, //  If set to true, will include stack trace for every dispatched action, so you can see it in trace tab jumping directly to that part of code
      traceLimit: 75, // maximum stack trace frames to be stored (in case trace option was provided as true)
      connectInZone: true, // If set to true, the connection is established within the Angular zone
    }),
  ],
});

And at counter.component.html
<div>Counτer : {{ counterFinal$ | async }}</div>
<button id="plus" (click)="plus()">+</button>
<button id="minus" (click)="minus()">-</button>
<button id="reset" (click)="reset()">Reset</button>

As a result I get this:

On ngRx Dev-tool my store looks to works fine. I just dont know how to get the counter property and display it on html (using async)

if I change the counter.component.html to this:
<div>Counτer : {{ (counterFinal$ | async).counter }}</div>
<button id="plus" (click)="plus()">+</button>
<button id="minus" (click)="minus()">-</button>
<button id="reset" (click)="reset()">Reset</button>

I get this error:
NG9: Property 'counter' does not exist on type 'number'. [plugin angular-compiler]

src/counter/counter.component.html:1:41:
  1 │ <div>Counτer : {{ (counterFinal$ |async).counter }}</div>
    ╵                                         ~~~~~~~

Error occurs in the template of component Counter.

src/counter/counter.component.ts:12:15:
  12 │   templateUrl: './counter.component.html',

Using Angular 17 with standalone component, and latest ngrx.
Thanks in advance!

Setting the type for the returning state in the select method seems to fix the issue.
We can also define an interface that contains details on the state property types.
  ...
  counterFinal$: Observable<CounterState>; //= this.store.select("counter");

  constructor(private store: Store<{ counter: CounterState }>) {
    //this.store.select('counter').subscribe(data => this.c = data.counter);
    this.counterFinal$ = this.store.select('counter');
  }
  ...

FULL CODE:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import {
  Action,
  ActionReducer,
  createReducer,
  on,
  provideStore,
} from '@ngrx/store';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable, map } from 'rxjs';
import { AsyncPipe, CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { createAction } from '@ngrx/store';

export interface CounterState {
  counter: number;
}

export const initialState: CounterState = {
  counter: 0,
};

export const plus = createAction('counter +');
export const minus = createAction('counter -');
export const reset = createAction('counter Reset');

export const CounterReducer = createReducer<
  CounterState,
  Action,
  ActionReducer<CounterState, Action>
>(
  initialState,
  on(plus, (state) => ({ ...state, counter: state.counter + 1 })),
  on(minus, (state) => ({ counter: state.counter - 1 })),
  on(reset, (state) => ({ counter: 0 }))
);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div>Counτer : {{ (counterFinal$ | async)?.counter || 0 }}</div>
    <button id="plus" (click)="plus()">+</button>
    <button id="minus" (click)="minus()">-</button>
    <button id="reset" (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  //c!:number;
  counterFinal$: Observable<CounterState>; //= this.store.select("counter");

  constructor(private store: Store<{ counter: CounterState }>) {
    //this.store.select('counter').subscribe(data => this.c = data.counter);
    this.counterFinal$ = this.store.select('counter');
  }

  plus() {
    //this.count = this.count + 1;
    console.log('+');
    this.store.dispatch(plus());
  }

  minus() {
    //this.count = this.count - 1;
    console.log('-');
    this.store.dispatch(minus());
  }

  reset() {
    //this.count = 0;
    console.log('0');
    this.store.dispatch(reset());
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideStore({ counter: CounterReducer })],
});

Stackblitz Demo

You are correct  but it's weird because I follow this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44296181/1281063
in which the Store returns the same type as the state's interface  e.g. CounterState.
and the Observable has the type of the state's property e.g. Observable
Why this happens?
One of those two (your answer or this answer) must be wrong.
I am curious not just for code working but also why..
Thanks for your answer any way

@Universe both the answers are the same, when we define the state we set the store type as AppStore which has a property clock: Date, when we select clock property, Date is returned as an observable, which easily fits into Observable<Date>, in your code the only problem was, you were giving Store<CounterState> which implies there is a store with name counter: number, but in actuality we have a interface like { counter: CounterState }, I hope I communicated it properly!

@Narem Murali
But the AppStore in the link is also an interface and regarding your says the select returns an interface like {clock: Date} , why my store returns {counter:CounterState} and not {counter:number}?

@Universe the key should be counter because we are accessing the counter this.store.select('counter'), the structure of the observable returned, will be of type CounterState!

@Narem Murali so the link example has an error: the returned observable will be of type AppStore and not Date. Am I correct?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Universe But their the state of reducer for clock is just a date, for us its a complex object, it confusing because they did not include the state part export const initialState: CounterState = {   counter: 0, };
